# iOS 7 Frame returns wrong height

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, frame, ios7

I just stumbled across a weird issue when testing my app with Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK. For some reason `self.view.frame` returns the wrong height for my view in `viewWillAppear`.

Testing in Xcode 5 with 4 inch retina iPhone simulator returns `{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}` although my UIViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController.

Testing in Xcode 4 with 4 inch retina iPhone simulator returns `{{0, 0}, {320, 504}}` which in my opinion is the correct height when wrapped in UINavigationController.

I made the tests with a naked single view controller project with storyboard.

Any ideas? When somebody needs further information - just ask - I will provide it as soon as possible.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remember the WWDC videos - views now run under translucent Navigation bars and the status bar, so you would expect the view to be the full height of the screen.

Comment: so how do we deal with that. I just disabled the translucent option in my storybaord but nothing happens.

Comment: OK got it - had to clean the project first. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you guys please point out what is the number of a session where this iOS7 behavior is described?

Comment: In my case (Xcode 5 and testing 3.5" and 4" retina phones) I experience those frame differences but in a different way. When in `viewDidLoad` both frame and bounds are {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}, which I think are the correct values. But then I call `presentViewController` and when I return and dismiss that modal, the frame is {{0, 64}, {320, 504}} and bounds is {{0, 0}, {320, 504}}. I still don't know the cause.